# Is it possible to dynamically discover tables in an Entity Framework model?

Tags: database, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I have co-workers working on an Entity Framework model that changes structure (entities), over time as software development progresses.  I've written some utilities that interact with the tables within the model, but I'd like to have the code dynamically discover the tables.  Is there a way I can do this ?  Perhaps with ADO.NET to get the table names and then store them in a collection ?

Thanks,

Scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse the .edmx file ?

Comment: I hadn't considered that.  Since it's just XML, that shouldn't be too hard.  Still wondering if there's another way.